# Python getting a __str__ method error

Tags: python, oop, constructor

I am learning about OOP from a Python programming book, and one of their examples is about using the `__str__()` function to display the attribute values via the `print()` statement. The book is unclear and I think I am missing something big here:

```
  class Product:
    def __init__(self, description, price, inventory):
        self.__description = description
        self.__price = price
        self.__inventory = inventory

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - price: {1:.2f}, inventory: {2:d}'.format(self.__description(), self.__price(), self.__inventory())

    def get_description(self):
        return self.__description

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def get_inventory(self):
        return self.__inventory
```

When I run the module, make an object, and use the `print()` function, I get the following error, which says "'str' object is not callable":

```
>>> prod1 = Product('tomato', 1.50, 20)
>>> print(prod1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(prod1)
  File "C:/Users/person/Documents/GitHub/pyprojects/inittest.py", line 8, in __str__
    return '{0} - price: {1:.2f}, inventory: {2:d}'.format(self.__description(), self.__price(), self.__inventory())
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

What should I do with the `__str__()` function? Thank you.

Comment: You're using `self.__description()`, but you really meant `self.__description`, or `self.get_description()`. Same goes for `self.__price()` and `self.__inventory()`.

Comment: Don't use `__` at the beginning of identifiers. That will invoke [private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) which usually does what you don't want and is not a substitute for `private` scoping in Java/C++

Comment: Don't write trivial "getters". They are an anti-pattern from C++/Java. Better to use `my_product.inventory` instead of `my_product.get_inventory()`. Unlike in other languages, if you need to add methods later to maintain member invariants, you can do so without changing every place where *.inventory is mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a string.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - price: {1:.2f}, inventory: {2:d}'.format(self.__description(), self.__price(), self.__inventory())
```

you need to either leave the "()" out:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - price: {1:.2f}, inventory: {2:d}'.format(self.__description, self.__price, self.__inventory)
```

or use the getter methods

```
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} - price: {1:.2f}, inventory: {2:d}'.format(self.get__description(), self.get__price(), self.get__inventory())
```